# org.JSONObject vs Map in Gson serialization

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a Java object which internally at some place has JSONObject. When serialising the object using Gson, i found a new key (map) present in the final results. I found the extra key is due to the JSONObject.

I wonder why the GSON serialisation differs when serialising JSONObject vs Map. Ideally both should give the same result right?

Sample snippet:

```
JSONObject ab = new JSONObject();
Map<String, String> ab1 = new HashMap<>();
System.out.println("JSONObject: " + new Gson().toJson(ab));
System.out.println("Map: " + new Gson().toJson(ab1));
```

And the output is

```
JSONObject: {"map":{}}
Map: {}
```

Comment: what are the contents of `ab` and `ab1`? Why do you think that JSONObject is supposed to give same result as a Map?

Comment: 1. If i do toString() of JSONObject and Map, i am getting the same result **{}**. 
2. JSONObject is a JSON and also the final output string from Gson is also a JSON. Why JSONObject should be converted again to JSON rather than just retaining it?

Comment: Thanks  @LyubomyrShaydariv. I got the answer from your comment.